# LINQ2SQL Expression - Conversion failed when converting date

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-sql

I have this Linq expression

```
var searchDate = DateTime.ParseExact("17.12.2018", "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                      DateTimeStyles.None);

result = result.Where(DatePredicate("LaunchWeekStartDate", searchDate, 3));
```

and I call this expression

```
public static Expression<Func<General, bool>> DatePredicate(string columnName, 
                                                            DateTime 
                                                            searchValue, 
                                                            int? operatorId)
{
  var type = typeof(General);
  var x = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
  var member = Expression.Property(x, columnName);
  Expression expression;

  var constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(DateTime));

  // Greater Than >
  if (operatorId == 2)
  {
    expression = Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant); // THIS THROW ERROR
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(expression, x);
  }

  // Less Than <
  else if (operatorId == 4)
  {
    expression = Expression.LessThan(member, constant); // THIS THROW ERROR
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(expression, x);
  }

  // Equal
  var column = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == columnName);

  expression = column == null
             ? expression = Expression.Constant(true) // THIS WORKS
             : expression = Expression.Equal(member, constant); // THIS THROW ERROR

  return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(expression, x);
}
```

The error that I am getting is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This works

```
var searchDate = DateTime.ParseExact("17.12.2018", "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                     DateTimeStyles.None);
result = result.Where(x => x.LaunchWeekStartDate == searchDate);
```

The database column and class property of LaunchWeekStartDate is of type DateTime.

```
public class General
    {
        [Key]
        public Int64 RowNumber {get; set;}
    // ...
        public DateTime LaunchWeekStartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Please, can you explain what is the issue here ?

**Edit:**

Instead of `Express.Equal` I am trying to use `Express.Call` with `CompareTo` method.

```
var member = Expression.Property(x, columnName);
MethodInfo method = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(DateTime) });
constant = Expression.Constant(searchValue, typeof(DateTime));
var call = Expression.Call(member, method, constant);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<General, bool>>(call, x);
```

But I am getting an exception that I don't understand:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'

Comment: What is the type of `x` in your lambda? What is the type of "x" in `DatePredicate`?

Comment: @NetMage I updated my question, it is simple class, only with properties.

Comment: Have you used LINQPad? With a slight clean-up, your code works fine against MS SQL Server. What exactly is the SQL being generated when you use `DataPredicate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works, i copied it from this 9 years old blog https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/231060-comparing-date-only-in-ef

```
expression = Expression.And(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Day").Single()),
                    Expression.Constant(searchValue.Day)
                    ),
                Expression.And(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Month").Single()),
                        Expression.Constant(searchValue.Month)
                        ),
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Year").Single()),
                        Expression.Constant(searchValue.Year)
                        )
                    )
                );
```

but it seems to me little bit complicated for such task.

Also i dont know, how to make `GreaterThan` and `LessThen` with this approach :/

**Edit :** Now it works also for Greater than and Less Than

```
// Greater Than >
expression = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Date").Single()), constant);

// Less Than <
expression = Expression.LessThan(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Date").Single()), constant);

// Equal
expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(member, typeof(DateTime).GetMember("Date").Single()), constant);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out my answer on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313535/how-to-fix-sqlerror-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-stri/67404913#67404913)

The solution is how to make EntityFramework generate an SqlCommand with parameters so that Data Type Mapping can convert the CLR DateTime to SQL Server equivalent.